# Crear un Modelo propio de usuarios y autenticar el ingreso

Tags: django, django-models, users-roles

Buenos días, cree mi propio modelo de usuarios en Django y la idea es usarlo para validar el ingreso al sistema sin usar el model.user que trae por defecto Django. como puedo hacer para que los usuarios se puedan logear en mi sistema?

Comment: La verdad la respuesta es bastante amplia como para explicarte todo el proceso por acá, eso se deja para un tutorial, pero lo que tendrias que hacer es crear un backend de autentificacion el cual al momento de buscar tu usuario busque el modelo de tu usuario y no el modelo de usuario de django que trae por defecto. Igual no se por que no quieres usar el modelo de usuarios de Django, ya que es muy completo y provee muchas cosas útiles, si te sirve te puedo explicar la creacion del backend de autentificacion

Comment: Si te agradeceria mucho

Answer (score 3):

Bueno, la verdad no se el porque no quieres usar el modelo de django de usuarios, en realidad pienso que te ofrece un millón de ventajas como para hacer un propio modelo, y el de los mas importantes es que no tendrás que diseñar un método para poder guardar contraseñas de manera segura, ya que este modelo lo hace por ti.

Django te ofrece muchas formas de poder **Extender** el modelo de `User` con el fin de que puedas tener muchos mas campos para guardar la información de tus usuarios, entre esas formas esta el hacer que tu modelo de usuario tenga una relación de uno a uno con el modelo de usuario de django, y la otra es extender de una clase base de usuario que contiene los métodos del usuario de django y crear tus propios campos, serian estas dos opciones:

1.Extender el modelo de User:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Empleado(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(User)
    edad = models.IntegerField()
    genero = ...
    fecha_nacimiento = ...
```

Y obtener el Usuario empleado así:

```
usuario = User.objects.get(id=id)
usuario.empleado.edad
```

2.Crear un Modelo que herede de una clase de usuario base:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
    # agregas tus otros campos, esta es una forma mas directa, ya que guardas todos los datos en la misma tabla
```

De la segunda forma lo que te ahorras es la consulta a la tabla de empleados, ya que puedes tener todos los datos en la misma tabla.

En el segundo caso, debes añadir esta linea en settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'
```

Ahora, para hacer la autentificacion efectiva debes crear un archivo que por convencion se llama 'backend.py' y debes agregar lo siguiente:

```
# debes importar tu modelo de usuario, independiente de cual sea
from yoursite.models import Usuario

class UserAuthentificacionBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = Usuario.objects.get(username=username)
            # en este punto, debes verificar la contraseña, yo lo hare como lo hace el modelo de usuario de django, siguiendo los metodos que trae este
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except Usuario.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return Usuario.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except:
            return None
```

La idea de el backend es una clase que herede de object con dos métodos importantes, get_user y authenticate, los cuales al ser llamado con los parametros indicados deben retornar el usuario en caso de que exista, o no retornar nada en el caso contrario.

**Nota:** Así como usa el `username` puede simplemente usar el email, o lo que quieras para hacer el login o la autentificación.

Por ultimo, lo que debes hacer es notificarle a Django que usarás un nuevo backend para la autentificación, haciendo lo siguiente:

En settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('ruta.a.tu.backend.UserAuthentificacionBackend',)
```

Ten en cuenta que las rutas son con puntos, donde llamas a una app (la app debe estar en INSTALLED_APPS) que seria la primera parte de la ruta, y cada separacion en puntos puede ser un directorio o un archivo, y el ultimo (en este caso UserAuthentificacionBackend) pertenece a la clase dentro de el archivo de la ruta.

Si cambias de modelo de usuario y no cambias el `AUTH_USER_MODEL` quizás no te funcione el administrador de Django

Cualquier duda, comenta